# Grails show and create returns xml rather than html

Tags: rest, grails

I had a Grails app up and running using the generate scripts but for one domain type I decided to try to return REST as well. I made changes to urlmapping and the controller as I investigated this. Sort of got it working but then noticed that though the index page for domain in the browser was correct, selecting individual records or creating new ones returned XML in the browser.

I have returned the controller and urlmapping to original state but still getting XML rather than HTML for that domain.

Any ideas where to look to fix this?

Comment: It is literally the code that is auto generated. Fortunately it is a demo app so I will start the process again from scratch and then do comparisons between files.

Comment: Whatever it is just post it, it is very hard to guess what is wrong without seeing any code

Comment: Found the mistake. I left a mapping in my domain code and removing that bought normality.